# CloudFormation EventBusPolicy: The relative-id "event-bus/bus_name" is invalid for ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, aws-cloudformation

According to [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-eventbuspolicy.html), I try:

```
  ebMailPolicy:
    Type: AWS::Events::EventBusPolicy
    Properties:
      EventBusName: !Ref ebMail
      StatementId: AllowForOrg
      Statement:
        Effect: Allow
        Action: events:PutEvents
        Condition:
          StringEquals:
            "aws:PrincipalOrgID": !Ref OrgId
        Principal: "*"
```

The error is:

`The relative-id "event-bus/bus_name" is invalid for ARN "arn:aws:events:eu-central-1:acc_id:event-bus/bus_name"`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The doc is wrong. Correct version:

```
  ebMailPolicy:
    Type: AWS::Events::EventBusPolicy
    Properties:
      EventBusName: !Ref ebMail
      StatementId: CrossAccSendEvents
      Action: events:PutEvents
      Principal: "*"
      Condition:
        Type: StringEquals
        Key: aws:PrincipalOrgID
        Value: !Ref OrgId
```

Answer (score 1):

The AWS document does not explicitly state it but this is what we have working

```
EventBusPolicy:
    Type: AWS::Events::EventBusPolicy
    DependsOn: CustomEventBridgeBus
    Properties:
      StatementId: "AllowSameAWSAccount"
      EventBusName: !Ref CustomEventBridgeBus
      Statement:
        Effect: "Allow"
        Principal:
          AWS: !ImportValue IntanceRoleArn
        Action: "events:PutEvents"
        Resource: !GetAtt CustomEventBridgeBus.Arn
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right! The AWS documentation isn't clear.

To allow restrict to a organization but allow all accounts in that organization you should do like as follows:

```yaml
  MyEventBusPolicy:
    Type: AWS::Events::EventBusPolicy
    Properties:
      Action: events:PutEvents
      StatementId: EveryAccountInTheOrgPolicy
      EventBusName: !Ref MySourceEventBusName
      Principal: "*" # Every account in that organization
      Condition:
        Type: StringEquals
        Key: aws:PrincipalOrgID
        Value: !Ref MyOrgId
```

To allow restrict to a organization/account you should do like as follows:

```yaml
  MyEventBusPolicy:
    Type: AWS::Events::EventBusPolicy
    Properties:
      Action: events:PutEvents
      StatementId: SomeAccountInTheOrgPolicy
      EventBusName: !Ref MySourceEventBusName
      Principal: !Ref MySourceAccountID
      Condition:
        Type: StringEquals
        Key: aws:PrincipalOrgID
        Value: !Ref MyOrgId
```

And allow cross account independently of the organization you should do like as follows:

```yaml
  MyEventBusPolicy:
    Type: AWS::Events::EventBusPolicy
    Properties:
      Action: events:PutEvents
      StatementId: SomeAccountPolicy
      EventBusName: !Ref MySourceEventBusName
      Principal: !Ref MySourceAccountID
```

Hope help other. I also spent a few hours making this work!